# GitLab email notification not working

Tags: git, email, notifications, smtp, gitlab

I just set up gitlab on my dedicated server, As Admin I created a new user, He should normally receive an email with his password, But He doesn't.

What I want to know is how to configure email notifications (with SMTP).

PS:  I'm not familiar with Ruby environment at all.

Thank you.

**Update : it works now, I just forgot to install postfix when setting up gitlab**

**Update 2 : Finally I've choose to use an SMTP account to send email notifications:**

Personally I've an Amazone account (You Can use Gmail) :

1) In /home/git/gitlab/config/envirenoments/production.rb comment this line :

```
#config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

2) Add this (with correct credentials) just before end tag :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => 'gmail.com', // Or an other SMTP provider 
     :port => 467, // Port depends on your provider
     :domain => 'gitlab.yourserver.com', // Your Gitlab main url
     :authentication => :plain,
     :user_name => 'your gmail id',
     :password => 'yourPassword',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

Thank you, I hope it gonna help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I've chosen to use an SMTP account to send email notifications:

Personally I've an Amazone account (You Can use Gmail) :

1) In /home/git/gitlab/config/envirenoments/production.rb comment this line :

```
#config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

2) Add this (with correct credentials) just before end tag :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => 'gmail.com', # Or an other SMTP provider 
     :port => 467, # Port depends on your provider
     :domain => 'gitlab.yourserver.com', # Your Gitlab main url
     :authentication => :plain,
     :user_name => 'your gmail id',
     :password => 'yourPassword',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Thank you, I hope it gonna help you.

Comment: You can't use Gmail, it sometimes doesnt send emails (randomly)

Answer (score -6):

Please follow the installation guide, it includes instructions for setting up email.

Comment: Even if it works, the last installation of postfix has removed some plesk packages (I'm managing my server with plesk), Now all the part concerning emails, redirecting, accounts, doesn't work anymore !

Comment: I assumed it was a dedicated server, as in dedicated to GitLab.